# Rollover effect using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be an easy question and I am over thinking it. I have a situation where I want to implement a Rollover effect.

I have Img1 which is a button. When a user hovers on Img1 another img in the container (Img2) will change to (Img3). When the user is no longer hovering over Img1 then Img3 will change back to Img2.

I hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

Thank you all for the help, it has been a pleasure knowing that there are so many people willing to help. I ended up choosing the answer that was simplest for me to use, so I apologize to offend anyone.

Here is my final answer (with code):

```
<!--SECTION 3-->
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--> 
<section id="s3">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/shopping.asp"><img class="btn" id="btn" src="/common/<%=site_version%>/img/s3_order_btn.png" draggable="false" alt=""></a>
        <img class="bulb" id="bulb" src="/common/<%=site_version%>/img/s3_bulb_noglow.png" draggable="false" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--> 
<!--END OF SECTION 3-->
<script>
$("#btn").hover(function(){
   // when mouseover
   $("#bulb").attr("src","/common/<%=site_version%>/img/s3_bulb_glow.png");
},
function() {
  // when mouseout
  $("#bulb").attr("src","/common/<%=site_version%>/img/s3_bulb_noglow.png");
});
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you're having trouble with. People can be harsh - they'll down vote your question if it looks like you're asking someone to "do your homework".

Comment: Please, provide the html

Comment: If you hover on the down vote button you'll see a tooltip explaining "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Your apparent lack of research into how to do this will result in down votes. (I see one already)

Comment: This isn't homework and there is not much HTML to paste. It's a container with one image and one image that **should** be changing, do you really need the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:-
i am here supposing Img1 Id is Img1 etc.

```
$("#Img1").hover(function(){
   // when mouseover
   $("#Img2").attr("src","paste your Img3 Url");
},
function() {
  // when mouseout
  $("#Img2").attr("src","paste your Img2 Url");
});
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: Please read the docs on `.hover()` before suggesting something like this.

Comment: This is perfect, and super simple. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I kept playing with the :hover effect and the inline onmouseover/onmouseout.

Comment: jQuery is fine, I have jQuery implemented for a slider I am using anyway. SteamDev, you don't think this is a good idea?

Comment: @SteamDev why down vote, this is not exact answer as i don't know image url also i don't know image id so i written in start that i am supposing Img1 as id

Comment: @SteamDev if you try this code this will work it is just for help.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter. But I guess it's because of the way you treat mouseout event. The `.hover()` function already receives two paremeters for mouseover and mouseout handlers.

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari the original answer was incorrect, but it has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something that could be done purely with HTML:

```
<div class="outerImage" style="width:64px; height:64px; background:blue url('outer_image.jpg');">
    <img class="innerImageDefault" src="image2.jpg">
    <img class="innerImageHover" src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
/* Position both of the inner images. */
.outerImage > img {
    float: right;
}

/* Hide the hidden image; hide the default image when hovered. */
.outerImage .innerImageHover,
.outerImage:hover .innerImageDefault {
     display: none;
 }

/* Show the hidden image when the outer image is hovered. */
.outerImage:hover .innerImageHover {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

A rather dirty [Proof of Concept on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o7g3rLd/)

Comment: I didn't know we can wrap img into img.

Comment: Thanks, we can't! I changed it to a `<div>` with a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS `:hover` selector?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="A">Hover me!</div>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    <div class="B">And I will highlight myself</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .4s;
    background: #fff;
}

div.container > div:hover ~ div {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1fwr9wfw/

In CSS, you can change the `background-image` too.

Answer (score 0):

If using the jQuery `.hover()` method, just know that it accepts two arguments:

```
$("#Img1").hover(function(){
  // mouse enter
  $("#Img2").attr("src","paste your Img3 Url");
}, function(){
  // mouse leave
  $("#Img2").attr("src","paste your Img2 Url");
});
```

There are other optimizations that could be made as well, like storing the original `Img2` src somewhere so you don't have to redefine a URL you already have, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your html looks so :

```
<img src="button.jpg" alt="button" id="mybutton" />
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="imagetochange" />
```

Use this javascript :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('mybutton');
    var img = document.getElementById('imagetochange');

    btn.onmouseover = function(){
        img.src = 'image2.jpg';
    };
    btn.onmouseout = function(){
        img.src = 'image1.jpg';
    };
};
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e08wkj48/)**