# How do I assign data when elements have the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep facing a small issue.. It's about Classes & IDs

Let's say I have a 2 div with 5 paragraphs in them, all paragraphs represent the same thing.
So the first paragraph represents Time, second one wether etc..

Now picture yourself adding a tooltip when hovering over the element that will 
display all the paragraphs.

If you want to change those values based on the one you are hovering over, how would you assign data to that specific class?
See this is bad.. Because Id's are unique

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="headLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">
  <div class="headSlot">
    <div class="itemImage" id="headSlot">

    </div>
    <section>
      <span class="tooltiptext">
                                    <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                    <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                    <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                </span>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>


<div class="topItems">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="capeLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">

    <section class="capeSlot">
      <div class="itemImage" id="capeSlot">

      </div>
      <span class="tooltiptext">
                                        <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                        <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                        <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                    </span>
    </section>
  </a>
```

But if I assign them classes instead of ID's how would I change the second divs content when hovering?

Because now I am doing this, which is bad.

```
$('.itemImage').mouseover(function(event){
    if(model != null){
        document.getElementById("itemInfoName").style.color = "Orange";
        document.getElementById("itemInfoName").innerHTML = model.Name;
        document.getElementById("aStab").innerHTML = "Stab: " + model.AStab;
        document.getElementById("aSlash").innerHTML = "Slash: " + model.ASlash;
        document.getElementById("aCrush").innerHTML = "Crush: " + model.ACrush;
        document.getElementById("aMagic").innerHTML = "Magic: " + model.AMagic;
        document.getElementById("aRange").innerHTML = "Range: " + model.ARange;

        document.getElementById("dStab").innerHTML = "Stab: " + model.DStab;
        document.getElementById("dSlash").innerHTML = "Slash: " + model.DSlash;
        document.getElementById("dCrush").innerHTML = "Crush: " + model.DCrush;
        document.getElementById("dMagic").innerHTML = "Magic: " + model.DMagic;
        document.getElementById("dRange").innerHTML = "Range: " + model.DRange;

        document.getElementById("mStrength").innerHTML = "Melee Strength: " + model.MeleeStrength;
        document.getElementById("rStrength").innerHTML = "Ranged Strength: " + model.RangedStrength;
        document.getElementById("mDamage").innerHTML = "Magic Damage: " + model.MagicDamage;
        document.getElementById("Prayer").innerHTML = "Prayer: " + model.Prayer;

    }

});
```

Comment: do you want to create tooltips using html css js ?

Comment: Yeah, the tooltip is working I just need to be able to change the data within it

Comment: Where does the `model` object come from? Can you summarize this code into a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the unexpected behavior? Stating that *"this is bad"*, is not really helpful.

Comment: Also, always avoid assigning the same id to different html elements. It is never a good idea.

Comment: That would be waaaaaay to much code for this post, it's a json object, the data works fine it's just the way I need to bind it when hovering over.

Comment: @jrook Yeah I know thats what the question is about, what do I do, I know having the same ID, and assigning data to that ID will only assign it to the first index, and if I change the ID's to Classes then how do I assign it?

Comment: You can take a look at current answers to get some hints. But my issue is that the code snippet in your question does not really do anything. Can you at least change it to run the code you have pasted? I still have no idea what is the element the user hovers over and what is actually expected to be displayed as tooltip.

Comment: I'll change it up a bit

Comment: *off-topic*: Keeping block elements inside inline elements is a bad idea, here it is `<span>`

Comment: @jrook Added a edit to the bottom of my question

Comment: i created one pen [here](https://codepen.io/webrexRavi/pen/OBOJVy) which can help you

Comment: In fact @MarkDenom I made few researches for your second question that I removed and here is where we answered it before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747087/rollover-effect-using-javascript . Instead using `$("#Img1").hover(function(){` use the selector that I shown you. `document.querySelectorAll(".test #aStab")[1];` don't forget `document.querySelectorAll(".test #aStab")[0]` is the first div with that class, and `document.querySelectorAll(".test #aStab")[1]` is the second one.

Answer (score -1):

You can identify the divs by different data attributes. Example, you have two elements with the same class 'tooltiptext'

```
<span class="tooltiptext">
```

you can add some data attr to differentiate it

```
<span class="tooltiptext" data-some-id="1">
```

Then you can select it by doing:

```
$(".tooltiptext[data-some-id='1']")
```

```html
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="headLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">
                        <div class="headSlot">
                            <div class="itemImage" id="headSlot">
    
                            </div>
                            <section>
                                <span class="tooltiptext">
                                    <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                    <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                    <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                </span>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </a>
    
    
                    <div class="topItems">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="capeLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">
                            
                                <section class="capeSlot">
                                    <div class="itemImage" id="capeSlot">
    
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                                        <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                        <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                        <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                    </span>
                                </section>
                        </a>
```

```js
$(".tooltiptext").on("mouseover", function(e){
  var el = $(e.currentTarget);
  $("#tip").html(el.data("tip"));
});


$(".tooltiptext").on("mouseout", function(e){
  var el = $(e.currentTarget);
  $("#tip").html("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tip"></div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="headLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">
                        <div class="headSlot">
                            <div class="itemImage" id="headSlot">
    
                            </div>
                            <section>
                                <span class="tooltiptext"  data-tip="my content1">
                                    <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                    <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                    <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                    <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                    <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                    <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                </span>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </a>
    
    
                    <div class="topItems">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="capeLeftSlot" class="itemSlot">
                            
                                <section class="capeSlot">
                                    <div class="itemImage" id="capeSlot">
    
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="tooltiptext" data-tip="my content2">
                                        <h3 id="itemInfoName">Item Name</h3>
                                        <h4>Attack bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="aStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aSlash">Slash: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aCrush">Crush: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aMagic">Range: +5</p>
                                        <p id="aRange">Range: +5</p>
    
                                        <h4>Defence bonuses</h4>
                                        <p id="dStab">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dSlash">Stab: +5</p>
                                        <p id="dCrush">Stab: +5</p>
                                    </span>
                                </section>
                        </a>
```

Comment: I was thinking more about the paragraphs. When hovering over the divs the paragraphs should change data, but how do I assign the data when they have the same class

Comment: You need to find all paragraphs in the first tooltiptext, right?

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Have a look at the attached snippet is this anything that helps?

Answer (score -1):

Put the tooltip span inside each of the paragraphs and set the css display properties by accessing the respective span element through p#myId > span { display:none; }, 
p#myId:hover > span {display:inline}. I admit I haven't tried it out yet, but it believe this should work. For the Javascript part you don't need mouseover functions, plain setting the element will do, saving you some lines of code, or just write the html.